# Excel: An indication that a small cell contains more information within that cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

When a cell  contains more information than the width of the cell allows, then content is hidden.

Is there any way to show this visually in Excel that this is the case (like an icon or similar)?

Comment: What is the real question here? Do you want content to be hidden in this manner or are you looking for the cells where this is the issue? If the latter, see http://superuser.com/questions/29265/how-can-i-get-a-cell-in-excel-to-automatically-adjust-its-height-to-fit-the-wrap

Comment: I don't know if there is an indicator built into excel. But what I usually do is select my worksheet then go to `Format` -> `AutoFit Column Width` and/or `AutoFit Column Height` if there's a possibility that it is needed.

Comment: This question asks something different from the proposed duplicate.  The request is not to make everything fit but to provide an indication when contents are not completely displayed.

Comment: you could use conditionnal formating (bold borders fro example) with the condition cell<>"" , but it'll highlight all cells with content, not only the one hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are too many variables at play here. The main factors would be: font family, font size, wrap text, merge, and which characters are used.

The following might be a close hack. You could loop through the columns (and/or rows) and store the width of each in an array. Autofit the columns. Loop through the columns again and test if the current width is the same as the original. If it is not, then change it back and add some sort of indicator. The indicator could be a background highlight, cell comment, etc.